# sending one email by wp_mail() BUT recive multiple

Tags: wordpress

To send the confirmation code in wordpress login form, I need to send an email to the user, but the email is sent multiple times to one user
`

```
<?php

//Config SMTP
define('SMTP_HOST', 'mail.x.ir');  // A2 Hosting server name. For example, "a2ss10.a2hosting.com"
define('SMTP_AUTH', true);
define('SMTP_PORT', '465');
define('SMTP_SECURE', 'ssl');
define('SMTP_USERNAME', 'tst@melad.ir');  // Username for SMTP authentication
define('SMTP_PASSWORD', 'x');          // Password for SMTP authentication
define('SMTP_FROM',     'x');  // SMTP From address
define('SMTP_FROMNAME', 'Developer');         // SMTP From name


add_action('phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email');
function send_smtp_email($phpmailer)
{
  $phpmailer->isSMTP();
  $phpmailer->Host       = SMTP_HOST;
  $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = SMTP_AUTH;
  $phpmailer->Port       = SMTP_PORT;
  $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
  $phpmailer->Username   = SMTP_USERNAME;
  $phpmailer->Password   = SMTP_PASSWORD;
  $phpmailer->From       = SMTP_FROM;
  $phpmailer->FromName   = SMTP_FROMNAME;
}

var_dump(wp_mail("x0@gmail.com", "Subject", 'your pass is: Me' . rand(100000, 999999)));
```

`

Comment: i sent test email by this config in 'WP Mail SMTP' wordpress plugin and work correctly

Comment: i problem solved, is calles wp_mail() direct in function, But when using the login form and using the ajax method, the problem was solved, of course, after a few days of fiddling with the codes.